# How to return list of JSON object form springMVC?

Tags: dojox.grid

How can i return List of json object like {"items":"["{"":""},{"":""},..."]"} form Spring MVC3.0? Please some one help on this...

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)//, headers=ACCEPT_JSON)
@ResponseBody
public List<User> userList() {
    LOG.info("get list of Users");

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    users.add(new User("user1", "pass1", "name1", Boolean.TRUE));
    users.add(new User("user2", "pass2", "name2", Boolean.TRUE));
    users.add(new User("user3", "pass3", "name3", Boolean.TRUE));

    return users;
}
```